# Risk-free arbitrage given a volume oracle?

Tags: volatility, arbitrage, volume

Given a magical oracle who can correctly predict the volume, but not the price, of a given security, does there exist a risk-free arbitrage to capitalize on this information?

Answer (score 2):

No, because the volume does not indicate the price change. E.g. the price change might net to zero over all times.